# how to include js file in php?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a problem with an js file in php.
if i include it like this:

```
?> <script type="text/javascript" href="file.js"></script> <?php
```

the file isn't included and i get an error that the function isn't defined.

When i try it this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="datetimepicker_css.js"></script>');
</script>
```

the first  tag in the document.write function closes `<script type="text/javascript">`

what is the correct way to do this?

thanks, 
sebastian

Answer (score 55, accepted):

PHP is completely irrelevant for what you are doing. The generated HTML is what counts.

In your case, you are missing the `src` attribute. Use

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
```

Comment: and if it doesn't come up in the head section? what can i do?

Comment: @sebastian: More specifically, just change "href" to "src". Here's a drop-in replacement for your original: `?> <script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script> <?php`.

Comment: I'm sorry but this answer isn't really true. If you want to reduce HTTP requests, PHP is in fact the answer. That way the script generates all the content for the browser rather than it having to fetch it from you or another web host. For example, including the jquery library instead of the actual jquery repository.

Comment: @Cl0ttERS this specific question is still not a PHP issue though. Everything the browser gets to see is the generated HTML; PHP only plays a role in generating it. It's true that you can use PHP to put all your stuff in one script, though (although that brings a new host of problems...)

Answer (score 9):

I found a different solution that I like:

```
<script>
    <?php require_once("/path/to/file.js");?>
</script>
```

Also works with style-tags and .css-files in the same way.

Comment: it will copy the script to the page

Comment: This was the correct answer for me. Thanks man

Comment: If this code runs multiple times it will generate empty script tags from the second occurrence onwards. This might or might not be the desired result depending on your use case.

Answer (score 3):

I have never been a fan of closing blocks of PHP to output content to the browser, I prefer to have my output captured so if at some point within my logic I decide I want to change my output (after output has already been sent) I can just delete the current buffer.

But as Pekka said, the main reason you are having issues with your javascript inclusion is because your using `href` to specify the location of the js file where as you should be using `src`.

If you have a functions file with your functions inside then add something like:

```
function js_link($src)
{
    if(file_exists("my/html/root/" . $src))
    {
        //we know it will exists within the HTTP Context
        return sprintf("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"%s\"></script>",$src);
    }
    return "<!-- Unable to load " . $src . "-->";
}
```

The n in your code without the need for closing your blocks with `?>` you can just use:

```
echo js_link("jquery/1.6/main.js");
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example you use the `href` attribute to tell where the JavaScript file can be found. This should be the `src` attribute:

```
?> <script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script> <?php
```

For more information see [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp).

Comment: *"Furthermore, JavaScripts should be added in the head section of the document."* No, they should be wherever the author thinks they should be. There's no reason at all you can't put `script` tags in your `body` section, and in fact there can be good reasons for doing so. Such as: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Comment: Oh? I was under the impression that it was only allowed in the head section. Thanks for the nice article on optimisation, I read straight away! :)

Comment: No worries. :-) The `script` tag can be used anywhere "metadata content" or "phrasing content" is expected; [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#script) *(blasted SO not underlining links)*, which is nearly anywhere in `head` or `body`. Most ad networks rely on `script` tags nested inside a site's markup.

Comment: @ThusithaSumanadasa You edit was incorrect. The `<script>`-tag is not PHP syntax and does not need to be processed by PHP, hence the closing PHP tag at the start and the (re)opening tag at the end. Furthermore, it is incorrect/not allowed to edit posts to fix things, one should use comments for it to notify the OP (and readers) about the (potential) mistake.

Answer (score 2):

[Pekka has the correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238353/how-to-include-js-file-in-php/4238363#4238363) (hence my making this answer a Community Wiki): Use `src`, not `href`, to specify the file.

Regarding:

> When i try it this way:
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="datetimepicker_css.js"></script>');
> </script>
> ```
>
> the first tag in the document.write function closes 
>   
> what is the correct way to do this?

You don't want or need `document.write` for this, but just in case you ever **do** need to put the characters `</script>` inside a `script` tag for some other reason: You do that by ensuring that the HTML parser (which doesn't understand JavaScript) doesn't see a literal `</script>`. There are a couple of ways of doing that. One way is to escape the `/` even though you don't need to:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
alert("<\/script>"); // Works, HTML parser doesn't see this as a closing script tag
//      ^--- note the seemingly-unnecessary backslash
</script>
```

Or if you're feeling more paranoid:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
alert("</scr" + "ipt>"); // Works, HTML parser doesn't see this as a closing script tag
</script>
```

...since in each case, JavaScript sees the string as `</script>` but the HTML parser doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between HTML output by PHP and a normal HTML page in this regard.

You should definitely not have to do the `document.write`. Your JS is not related to your PHP, so there must be some other error (like the file path) in the first example.

On a side note, you'll have problems using `</script>` within a script. The HTML parser sees the closing script tag when scanning the JS before parsing it, and becomes confused. You see people doing things like `'<'+'/script'` for this reason.

Edit:

As T.J. Crowder pointed out, actually you need to change `'href` to `src` in the `<script>` tag. Oops, actually Pekka pointed that out in his answer itself, so actually adding it here is totally superfluous.

Comment: It was Pekka, rather than I, who got there first. :-) I just tried to clarify his answer a bit, since he'd trimmed off the PHP stuff.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Oh, duh... I missed that detail in Pekka's comment originally... maybe he edited it? Or maybe I should try sleeping in a more regular pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Its more likely that the path to file.js from the page is what is wrong.
as long as when you view the page, and view-source you see the tag, its working, now its time to debug whether or not your path is too relative, maybe you need a / in front of it.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this, I've got something like

`script type="text/javascript" src="createDiv.php?id=" script`

AND In **createDiv.php** I Have

`document getElementbyid(imgslide).appendchild(imgslide5).innerHTML = 'php echo $helloworld; ';`

And I got supermad because the php at the beginning of the **createDiv.php** I made the `$helloWorld` php variable was formatted cut and paste from the html page

But it wouldn't work cause Of whitespaces was anyone gonna tell anyone about the whitespace problem cause my real php whitespace still works but not this one.

Answer (score -3):

If you truly wish to use PHP, you could use

```
include "file.php";
```

or

```
require "file.php";
```

and then in file.php, use a heredoc & echo it in.

```
file.php contents:
$some_js_code <<<_code
function myFunction()
{
   Alert("Some JS code would go here.");
}
_code;
```

At the top of your PHP file, bring in the file using either include or require
then in head (or body section) echo it in

```
<?php
require "file.php";
?>
<html>
<head>
<?php
echo $some_js_code;
?>
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Different way but it works. Just my $.02...