# How to use code from external .js files in blade.php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have resources/js/jquery.js files where I listen to button be pressed threw jQuery, and do some actions. The problem is that I can't import jquery.js into my .blade.php.

I added jquery.min.js into by public/js.

What I have in **.blade.php**

```
<form id="RegisterForm" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password">
    <input type="text" name="password2" id="password2">
    <input type="submit" value="REGISTER" id="registerButton">
</form>
<script src="{{asset('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

What I have in **jquery.js**

```
window.onload = function(){
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#registerButton').click(function(){
        alert("Hello");
    });
 });
}
```

I need to get `alert("Hello");`

The problem is that when click to the button nothing happens, I'm not sure if it bcs I added jquery.min.js wrongly, or just including my jquery.js script is wrong. Or this is impossible and I have to add this in the bottom of the body in my .blade.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#registerButton').click(function(){
                alert("Hello");
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please look into your browsers developer tool under network if the jquery.js is loaded or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to include js file in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238353/how-to-include-js-file-in-php)

Comment: @ThomasDeutschländer jqury.min.js is loaded, but jqury.js responses 404

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we assuming you have your js folders inside public/assets
Then 
**Add external js something like this.**

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}></script>
```

> And Add space after/before 2 Curly brackets.

I hope your problem will be resolve

Comment: I dont have assets in my public folder, jqury.min.js is inside public/js, while jquery.js is /resources/js, should I create assets by my own and move jqury.js in here?

Comment: Plase use js something like this.
{{ HTML::script('js/jquery.min.js'); }}

Comment: This code triggers error 
syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')' (View: /home/ordec/laraProjects/Blog/resources/views/register.blade.php)

Comment: Please remove semicolumn the try again like something 
{{ HTML::script('js/jquery.min.js') }}

Comment: I did everything, errors dissapeared but still err 404 in jquery.js

Comment: If possible then Please moved js in folder public/assets and use script code which is mentioned above.

Comment: I create assets in public folder, and moved jquery.js in here, but still err 404. I also tried to move whole js folder from resources, but still err 404

Comment: I moved jquery.js file from resources/js to the public/js and it works, but I worry even if it works, is it right to way to do it?

Comment: @ordec It was good to hear that your problem would be resolved.Can you please validate this answer? Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196772/discussion-between-sanjay-sisodiya-and-ordec).